# How do I show continuous image of complete space is complete?

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is uniformly continuous and $X$ is complete then so is $f(X)$?

My idea is that this is not true. $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$,
by $f(x)=tan^{-1}(x)$.

I think this result is true only if $f(X)=Y$.

Can anyone suggest some comments on this idea?

Comment: Your example satisifies $f(X)=f(\mathbb{R})=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)=Y$ though. Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392934/do-uniformly-continuous-functions-map-complete-sets-to-complete-sets?rq=1) ?